# Using GraphicsServices.h/GSEvent as well as compiling CLI iPhone tools with Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, jailbreak, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

I sent this to KennyTM (has all the private framework headers on GitHub) but I figured I'd ask here too just in case someone has some good ideas or any way to help me out.

I'm trying to write a command line utility that sends GSEvents to operate the keyboard, touch/drag elements onscreen, and operate hardware buttons (volume, home, sleep, etc.)

I grabbed the MouseSupport code and tried to look through it, but I couldn't find the easiest way to send GSEvents. I'm hoping someone here can help me.

First, what's the simplest way to declare a GSEvent and send it? I looked at the iPhone development wiki, but the documentation was very vague. I understand that there's a purple event port (?) that I have to send these events to, but I don't understand how to do that. Could someone offer examples for, say, touching at a coordinate, typing a certain key, or pressing a hardware button?

Also, do I have to write or do anything special if I want this utility to operate all applications as well as Springboard? I don't know if this is a special case because I want it at the OS level. Ideally, I would SSH into the phone, start the program, and it would send GSEvents that would be handled by whatever application was open.

As far as compiling this code, is there any way to do so under Xcode? I don't know what sort of project template I should use (if any) and this is throwing me off. I don't need "build and go" support, I'm more than happy to scp the program over to the phone. I understand that compiling the code is also feasible on the phone. I have all of the headers from the SDK on my phone along with iphone-gcc, but when compiling some test programs I still get errors about not finding mach headers and CoreFoundation. Is there an easier way to do this?

Lastly, are there other guides or pieces of literature that anyone can point me towards for learning more about this? I'm excited to get into open iPhone development (I have experience with the official SDK, but I want to go deeper).

Thanks for any and all help people can offer!

Comment: Hey Kenny, I sent it to your GitHub account. I could not find your email address or a way to send you a StackOverflow PM.

Comment: Ah ok, seen it. BTW, there's no PM on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I look forward to reading your response and doing some more iPhone development! Hopefully I can get some stuff hosted on a repo for Cydia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, what's the simplest way to declare a GSEvent and send it?

It depends on the type of the GSEvent. Some events have convenient functions that can be created and sent in one step, e.g. `GSEventLockDevice()`. But HID events (touches, key presses, etc.) do not have these simple functions. The reason is likely because `GSEventLockDevice()` etc are to be sent *from* the app to SpringBoard, but HID events are sent *from* SpringBoard to an app. Therefore, only the SpringBoard team needs to know how to construct a complicated GSEvent.

Anyway, to create a HID event (e.g. accelerometer event) you don't need to create a GSEvent. Just use `GSSendEvent()`:

```
// (not tested.)

GSAccelerometerInfo accel = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
GSEventRecord header;
memset(&header, 0, sizeof(header));
header.type = kGSEventAccelerate;
header.infoSize = sizeof(accel);
header.timestamp = mach_absolute_time();
// fill in other members.

struct {
  GSEventRecord record;
  GSAccelerometerInfo info;
} record = {header, accel};

// ... see below ...

GSSendEvent(&record, thePortOfApp);
```

But what is "the port of app"? Unfortunately there's no function to get that. As of 3.1, the name of the mach port is same as its bundle ID, so you could use:

```
mach_port_t thePortOfApp = GSCopyPurpleNamedPort("com.unknown.appBundleID");
...
mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), thePortOfApp); // remember to release the port.
```

---

> Also, do I have to write or do anything special if I want this utility to operate all applications as well as Springboard?

As far as I know, no.

---

For the other two, probably you should split them into individual questions.

Comment: Kenny,

Thanks so much for answering my question! I unfortunately can't seem to figure out how to create other events. For example, using `GSSendSimpleEvent()` seems to not work for any GSEventType. I've tried menu button presses, volume keys, everything. Am I misusing this function to assume I only need to do `GSSendSimpleEvent(kGSEventLockDevice, app_port)`? Could you help me with this and other hardware buttons? Also, could you provide information on what needs to be included with touch events and keyboard events? Thanks again!

Comment: @Peter: Yes, but only the SpringBoard will respond to the Lock device event. Use `GSEventLockDevice()` in that case.

Comment: I see, what other events can only be handled by Springboard?

If possible, could you clarify how to create a touch event or keyboard event in the simplest way possible? Thanks again!

Comment: Kenny, I'm still looking for the easiest way to create a touch event that's sent to the running application/Springboard. Do you have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: @KennyTM from we get apple private framework, and how to add those in our application